# How to write Select query with dynamic table name in Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am writing a stored-procedure. But the table name is dynamic in this procedure. I want to get row number from my variable table. But where will I set `@rownumber` with return of select query?

```
Create Proc update_eMail
    (@tablename nvarchar(50),
     @columnname nvarchar(50))
AS
Begin 

    Declare @q_getrowNumber NVARCHAR(MAX)
    Declare @rownumber int
    SELECT @rownumber =  Count(ID) FROM  quotename(@tablename) // doesnt work

END
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write wrong Procedure for dynamic query
Try This. It will Work.

```
ALTER PROC update_eMail(@tablename NVARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN 
DECLARE @RowNumber NVARCHAR(MAX)=''

  set @RowNumber='select Count(ID) FROM '+@tablename+''
  exec(@RowNumber)
END
```

OR Try below Code in your Query

```
ALTER PROC update_eMail1
(
   @tablename NVARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)= '',@rownumber INT
     SET @sql = 'SELECT @rownumber = Count(ID) FROM '+quotename(@tablename) 

   EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@rownumber int output',@rownumber OUTPUT

   SELECT @rownumber

END
```

Comment: If I write some codes after the 'EXEC' code line, does it work? Is there run only one EXEC method in one stored procedure?

Comment: Yes, It works. You can write codes after 'Exec' code line.

Comment: You can run multiple stored procedure inside another stored procedure its limit upto 32 levels

Comment: Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to achieve the goal using dynamic sql

```
declare @sql NVARCHAR(4000)= ''

set @sql = 'SELECT @rownumber = Count(ID) FROM '+ quotename(@tablename) 

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@rownumber int output',@rownumber output
```

Comment: I update like this, but code finish in this line : ''exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@rownumber int output',@rownumber output '' The rest of my code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This one will be easiest for you:

```
Create Proc update_eMail
    @tablename nvarchar(50)
AS
Begin 
    EXEC ( 'SELECT Count(ID) FROM '+@tablename+'')
END
```