# Dynamic Query : How to define Table Name or other String in SQL-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

I have the following 2 queries that should return the same information.

One normal query and the dynamic query which does not retrieve any result because of the @TABLENAME variable naming I guess.

```
DECLARE @TABLENAME as NVARCHAR (MAX)
SET @TABLENAME = 'MyTable'
```

Query Returning Results

```
select *  from jfa.[dbo].[MyTable]  
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = @TableName and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION = 2
```

Dynamic Query that does not return any result

```
DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'select *  from jfa.[dbo].[MyTable]  
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = ''@TableName'' and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION = 2'

    exec sp_executeSQL @sql,
    N'@TABLENAME nvarchar',
    @TABLENAME
```

I guess the problem is in the following line:

```
 on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = ''@TableName''
```

But I have tried several things an no success.

Many thanks in advance,

Kat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write Select query with dynamic table name in Stored Procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233532/how-to-write-select-query-with-dynamic-table-name-in-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
N'@TABLENAME nvarchar',
```

This code means that variable `@TABLENAME` is `nvarchar(1)`. Change it to e.g.

```
N'@TABLENAME nvarchar(45)',
```

Also you have to delete double `'` from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = ''@TableName''`.
So your code will look like:

```
DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'select *  from jfa.[dbo].[MyTable]  
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = @TableName --change here
and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION = 2'

    exec sp_executeSQL @sql,
    N'@TABLENAME nvarchar(45)', --change here
    @TABLENAME
```

However, if you want to dynamically change table from which you are selecting data, then you have to change static `jfa.[dbo].[MyTable]` to `jfa.[dbo].'+@TableName+'`. Finally, your query will look like:

```
DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'select *  from jfa.[dbo].'+@TableName+'  --change here 
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = @TableName --change here
and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION = 2'

    exec sp_executeSQL @sql,
    N'@TABLENAME nvarchar(45)', --change here
    @TABLENAME
```

Comment: Thanks Rokuto, I adapted it, I also defined for other Varchar (45). When inserting into the table it was just adding the first char.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
...
set @sql = 'select *  from jfa.[dbo].[MyTable]  
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = ' + @TableName + ' and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION = 2'
...
```

You need to concatenate the parameter value directly to the dynamic sql query, so use `...' + @TableName + ' ...`